# Lumia 820's Adobe PDF always asks whether a file should be replaced.

Tags: pdf

I have the problem that every time when I try opening a pdf file on my windows phone, Adobe PDF asks me "name.pdf already exists. Do you want to replace this file." What is the meaning of this and how can I get rid of it. 
I have the feeling that all the files I open are being stored in the Documents folder of Adobe PDF which is filling my phone with duplicates. A rather undesirable feature. 
I would appreciate your help.

Comment: delete adobe and install foxit

Answer (score 2):

Adobe always saves the files, if you open them again you need to replace them..
This is just so that you can read them later without internet connection
Just open Adobe and see the files you have there